# How to keep IOS 6 design in my application on IOS7

Tags: ios6, interface, ios7

I want to keep my IOS 6 design on a IOS7 device. I build with the IOS6 sdk but the interface is still with IOS7 controls on a IOS7 device.

How can I keep my IOS6 interface ?

Comment: If you already have a iOS 6 app, it will work as an iOS 6 app and look like an iOS 6 app on iOS 7 device.

Comment: Until you decide to do an update to that app using `xcode 5`, @Anthony just move with the times all your going to get otherwise is criticism because you haven't moved on.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended by apple, but develop your application with `XCode` prior to `XCode 5`, application's look and feel will remain same as `iOS6` in `iOS 7`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see both versions designs in interface builder.

[image]